# How to avoid Observable inside Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service with http request which return Observables of my Headlines

servise.ts

```
get(sort: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url, {...});
})

delete(id) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/${id}`, {...});
}
```

and in my component I have a function that set `this.headlines` from service get request. It looks like this:

```
interface IRes {
  searches: {
    label: string,
    id: number,
    value: string,
    ...
  }
}
headlines = [];

loadHeadlines() {
  this.service.get(data).subscribe((res: IRes) => this.headlines= res.headlines);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes I receive headline with empty label and don't need to show them, so I need to filter it and send .delete() request for this headlines. I tried something like this( The idea was to add `.pipe` before `subscribe` and call inside another subscribe.)
Something like that

```
loadHeadlines() {
  this.service.get(data)
    .pipe(
      map(res: IRes => {
        res.headlines.filter(headline => !!headline.label.trim())
          .forEach(headline => this.service.delete(headline.id).subscribe())
      })
    )
    .subscribe((res: IRes) => this.headlines= res.headlines);
}
```

but not sure that it's good idea. Which method would be better here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RxJS `switchMap` operator to map from one observable to another and `forkJoin` function to combine multiple observables. I've also used `iif` (with `of`) function to check if there are any empty `headline`s to be deleted.

But I fail to understand the condition you're using at the moment. It seems you're removing all the `headline` elements with empty `label` property while invoking `delete` on the rest. So essentially you're calling `delete` on all the valid elements. Perhaps it must be adjusted.

Try the following

```js
import { iif, forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

loadHeadlines() {
  this.service.get(data).pipe(
    switchMap((res: IRes) => {
      const emptyHeadlines = res.headlines.filter(headline => !headline.label.trim()); // <-- all headlines with empty labels
      const deletes$ = forkJoin(
        emptyHeadlines.map(headline => this.service.delete(headline.id))
      ).pipe(
        map(_ =>  ({     // <-- map back to return only the headlines with defined `label`
          ...res,
          headlines: headlines.filter(headline => !!headline.label.trim())
        }))
      );
      return iif(
        () => !!emptyHeadlines.length,
        deletes$, // <-- execute delete only if there are empty headlines 
        of(res)   // <-- if not forward the response
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(
    (res: IRes) => this.headlines = res.headlines,
    (error: any) => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's brilliant! Except one think, I've just tested this code and found that if delete step works than for `subscribe()` I already return `res.headlines` and in this case all logic for `this.headlines` broke (as it looks like `this.headlines = res.headlines.headlines`), but on second click, when all empty labels were deleted and this step skips everything works fine again

Comment: @MarkMark: An overlook on my part. I return only the `headlines` array from the `map` piped to the `forkJoin`. I've edited the answer to return the whole object with the filtered `headlines` array property. Please check if it works now.

Comment: Yes, I've also rewrote it in the same way, it works/ Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

well, `!!headline.label.trim()` definitely isn't a good idea, because the double `!` will delete all headlines that are NOT empty. also that `map` should be a `tap`.

so for the complete pipe:

```
this.service.get(data).pipe(
    map(res => res.headlines)
    tap(headlines => headlines.filter(headline => !headline.label.trim()).forEach(
        headline => this.service.delete(headline.id)
    )),
    map(headlines => headlines.filter(headline => !!headline.label.trim())),
).subscribe(headlines => this.headlines= headlines);
```

In a real scenario, i'd leave this to be handled by the backend. But tbh, this is strongly opinionated, as there is no objective right/wrong here.